# How to Access each elements in the following json output

Tags: json, model-view-controller

Here is my j-son output and i want to access inner elements element.
how should i do that?
i have tried to access them in the following way 
data[10];
but it didn't worked

```
public JsonResult ShowEventsList()
        {
            using (EventSchedularEntities db = new EventSchedularEntities())
            {
                var EventsList = from evnt in db.Events
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     id = evnt.EventID,
                                     Subject = evnt.EventName,

                                     Description = evnt.EventDesc,
                                     StartTime = evnt.EventDateBegin,
                                     EndTime = evnt.EventDateEnd,
                                     Color = evnt.Importance,

                                 };
                List<object[]> LstEvents = new List<object[]>();
                foreach (var ev in EventsList)
                {
                    LstEvents.Add(new object[] { ev.id, ev.Subject, ev.Description,DateTime.Parse(ev.StartTime.ToString()).ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm").Replace("-", "/"), DateTime.Parse(ev.EndTime.ToString()).ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm").Replace("-", "/"), ev.Color });
                }

                return Json( LstEvents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }

        }



    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../EventScheduler/ShowEventsList",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (result)
        {

            var data = JSON.parse(result);
            alert(data);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your sample json?

Comment: Updated. i want to access each and every value in that array(Ex: the Date). will it be possible?

Comment: its possible but value of  EventScheduler/ShowEventsList  i dont know . can you post it as json . result of alert(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: you can handle json very easy from javascript . if it is a valid one.

Comment: stringify used to make json object to string . if you can post that json i can help you.   like   var data = JSON.parse(result);  data[0]. EndTime like this you can access . or by a loop

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(result[1]);
 alert(data[0]); this did the trick